# order a dataframe according to a given list in R

Tags: r

I have a function where i calculate count of a column in R
I want to arrange my dataframe entries according to a given list passed to a function

input appeared in this form:

```
complete( c(2, 55, 8, 111, 12))
complete(30:25)
```

I have my data frame in ascending order by id, i want it to be arranged according to list given

```
id   nobs
2    463
8    586
12   338
55   711
111  932
```

Should be sorted / rearranged  as:

```
id   nobs
2    463
55   711
8    586
111  932
12   338
```

Comment: you don't have to order them, this is just indexing. at the end of your `complete` function, have it return the data frame, `df`, as `df[df$id %in% x, ]` where x is the arg given to `complete`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible approach using merge :

```
# data.frame to sort
DF <- 
read.csv(text=
'id,nobs
2,463
8,586
12,338
55,711
111,932')

# keys to use for sorting
keys <- c(2, 55, 8, 111, 12)

keyDF <- data.frame(key=keys,weight=1:length(keys))

merged <- merge(DF,keyDF,by.x='id',by.y='key',all.x=T,all.y=F)
res <- merged[order(merged$weight),c('id','nobs')]

> res
   id nobs
1   2  463
4  55  711
2   8  586
5 111  932
3  12  338
```

**N.B.**

- in case your data.frame `id` contains values not present in the `key` vector, those will go to the bottom of the data.frame.
- in case of duplicated ids, they will be kept adjacent after sorting.

Comment: is there a way to change the numbering on side as well? 1,4,2,5,3 ->>>1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Yes : `row.names(res) <- 1:nrow(res)`